# Stats by User Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, web-analytics

On SharePoint Online, is there a way to get visitor stats by User Group?

For example I'd like to see the number of pageviews by Owners, Members, Visitors.

I have no idea where to start and I am open to any suggestion (out of the box, third party app, Google Analytics, etc.).

Thanks!

Comment: You have the excel file from audit reports. Can't you do it manually?

Comment: @XristosK could you please elaborate? I can get audit and usage reports, but I don't see how this will give me for example the number of times a document or a page has been viewed by members.

Comment: You can explore the Popularity Trends option in SharePoint, it provides you number of unique users, but not sure it will provide you stats by user group.

Comment: @Unnie as far as I know it doesn't, hence my question.